# How to get MYSQL information schema column names with filled out count?

Tags: mysql

I tried to get all column names of specific table from information schema in MYSQL and I did it very well.

**Now I want to append the count of filled out(the column should not be null) of each column in front of their name.**

Here is my query:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'hr_db'
AND table_name = "employee_tbl"
```

The above query result is:

```
COLUMN_NAME
+-----------
id
------------
name
------------
phone
------------
email
```

But what I want is like below:

```
COLUMN_NAME   COUNT
+------------------
id            20
-------------------
name          20
-------------------
phone         12
-------------------
email         5
```

Thanks in advance for your comments and answers

Comment: What is that COUNT mean? Where do you get it from?

Comment: That count means the count of values for each column that should not be null.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 2):

It's relatively easy using prepared statements to get one row of totals
for example

```
set @sql = (
concat('select ',
(
select group_concat(concat('count(',column_name,') as ',column_name)) 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'users' and table_schema = 'sandbox'
)
, ' from users')
);

prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;

+----+------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+-----+-----+------------+----+
| id | name | password | email | firstname | lastname | sal | age | event_date | ts |
+----+------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+-----+-----+------------+----+
|  6 |    3 |        2 |     0 |         1 |        3 |   2 |   0 |          4 |  6 |
+----+------+----------+-------+-----------+----------+-----+-----+------------+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want 1 row per column then because mysql does not have an unpivot funtion you could

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
create procedure p(inschema varchar(100), intable varchar(100))
begin

declare cname varchar(100);
declare done int default false;

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT column_name from information_schema.columns
        where table_schema = inschema and table_name = intable
          order by ordinal_position;

DECLARE CONTINUE handler FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur;
    set @sql = '';
    LOOP1: LOOP
        #set no_more_rows1 = false;
        FETCH cur INTO cname;
        IF done THEN
            CLOSE cur;
            LEAVE LOOP1;
        END IF;

        set @sql = concat(@sql, 'select ', char(39),cname,char(39), ', count(', cname, ') as count from ' , intable, ' union ');

    END LOOP LOOP1; 
     set @sql = concat(substring(@sql,1,length(@sql) - 7),';');    
    prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
    execute sqlstmt;
    deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
end $$
delimiter ;


call p('sandbox','users');
+------------+-------+
| id         | count |
+------------+-------+
| id         |     6 |
| name       |     3 |
| password   |     2 |
| email      |     0 |
| firstname  |     1 |
| lastname   |     3 |
| sal        |     2 |
| age        |     0 |
| event_date |     4 |
| ts         |     6 |
+------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Or if you don't like a procedure then something like this

```
set @sql = 
(
select group_concat(concat('select ' ,char(39),column_name,char(39), ',count(' , column_name, ') from users union ' ))
from information_schema.`COLUMNS` where table_schema = 'sandbox' and table_name = 'users'
);

set @sql = replace(@sql,'union ,','union ');

set @sql = concat(substring(@sql,1,length(@sql) - 7),';'); 
prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
```

Comment: @P.Salmnon is it possible to show column names vertically?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on and do you have any other technologies available to you?

Comment: Mysql version is 5.6, Sorry what kind of technologies? we are working with PHP Framework CodeIgniter.

Comment: MYSQL 5.6 does not have an unpivot function so you can either unpivot in php or amend the my code to run a bunch of select..unions in a procedure. I suspect php would perform better. I will add an illustrative procedure shortly

Comment: I know how to do it with PHP script but it would be better to do it with Mysql.

Comment: Better, How I wonder. Have edited to include a procedure to produce 1 row per column.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by regular select:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`), COUNT(`name`), COUNT(`phone`), COUNT(`email`) FROM `employee_tbl`;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if my table contains about 100 columns then, should I put them like above?